# how to capture the result of `git status` in a Rails action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capture

If you run this code in a controller action (notice the backticks)

```
def index
  …
  `pwd >> tc.log` 
  `git status >> tc.log`
  `ls >> tc.log`
  …
end
```

, only the 1st and 3rd command will pipe their output to the tc.log file.

I'm trying to get the output of `git status` (f.ex) in a controller action and have tried many variations (capturing stdout, piping to a file, open3, ..) to no avail.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Dude check out [ruby-git](http://github.com/schacon/ruby-git). Wraps up git commands in Ruby objects!

Answer (score 2):

This is a total shot in the dark, but `git status` might not be writing to stdout.

Try doing something like:

```
`git status >> tc.log 2>&1`
```

Comment: No problem.  Just so you know, 2>&1 will pipe both the stdout and stderr streams.